# Facebook ads tracker for android: no actions reported

Tags: android, facebook, ads

We have integreated Facebook Mobile App Ads for Installs SDK into our iOS and Android app. 
Code for iOS:
Facebook SDK 3.5 (inside function applicationDidBecomeActive)

```
    [FBSettings publishInstall:@"APP_ID"];
```

Code for Android:
Facebook SDK 3.5 (inside `onResume()`)

```
    com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp( MyActivity.this, getString( R.string.fb_app_id ) );
```

Clicks are being reported correctly, but not installs. For the iOS it is OK, but Android shows nothing in Actions column inside Campaign monitor https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/.

We have checked settings of Facebook app and both Android and iOS have last install date correct on the dashboard in section "Last mobile install reported" (usually 10-20 minutes earlier). It seems like Android just does not show data in the Actions column. I can not estimate cost per action for this app which is very important when planning budget for ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error on Facebook side. Now everything works as expected.